# Workflow Stopped working correctly

Tags: 2013, designer-workflow

I have a workflow that HAD been working for the past few weeks with no problems.  Yesterday I noticed the last part of the workflow task wasn't completing.  Basically, it's a leave request workflow.  Once leave is approved, appointment time is added to the department calendar with basic information. Then, it is also posted to the Admin Calendar (Which only a few people have access to), with more detailed information.  The workflow no longer posts to the Admin Calendar.  I have double checked permissions and republished my workflow, but still nothing. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can move your logic in APP step and see this is a permission issue. APP step will run with elevated privileges.

However, you can you also see the error logging in the workflow history to get specific information.

Comment: Sorry, I am pretty new to Sharepoint.  What do you mean by move by logic in APP?  Also, can you tell me how I can very the workflow history?

Comment: On another note, I know it has to do with permissions. Testing some things out and added one of the employees with Contribute rights. The workflow completed successfully. Problem is now she can view the admin calendar. How can I allow her to have rights to basically add items to the list, but not view them?

Comment: You can refer following article to understand the APP Step in SPD workflow. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822159.aspx